# RedVox Python SDK | Not Reading in .rdvxz Files

Tags: python, file

I'm attempting to read in a series of files for processing contained in a single directory using RedVox:

```
input_directory = "/home/ben/Documents/Data/F1D1/21" # file location
rdvx_data = DataWindow(input_dir=input_directory, apply_correction=False, debug=True) # using RedVox to read in the files

print(os.listdir(input_directory)) # verifying the files actually exist...
# returns "['file1.rdvxz', 'file2.rdvxz', file3.rdvxz', ...etc]", they exist

# write audio portion to file
rdvx_data.to_json_file(base_dir=output_rpd_directory,
                    file_name=output_filename)

# this never runs, because rdvx_data.stations = [] (verified through debugging)
for station in rdvx_data.stations:
    # some code here
```

Enabling debugging through arguments as seen above does not provide an extra details. In fact, there is no error message whatsoever. It writes the JSON file and pickle to disk, but the JSON file is full of null values and the pickle object is just a shell, no contents. So the files definitely exist, os.listdir() sees them, but RedVox does not.

I assume this is some very silly error or lack of understanding on my part. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have not worked with RedVox previously, nor do I have much understanding of what these files contain other than some audio data and some other data. I've simply been tasked with opening them to work on a model to analyze the data within.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Not sure why the previous code doesn't work (it was handed to me), however, I worked around the DataWindow call and went straight to calling the "redvox.api900.reader" object:

```
from redvox.api900 import reader

dataset_dir = "/home/*****/Documents/Data/F1D1/21/"

rdvx_files = glob(dataset_dir+"*.rdvxz")
for file in rdvx_files:
    wrapped_packet = reader.read_rdvxz_file(file)
```

From here I can view all of the sensor data within:

```
if wrapped_packet.has_microphone_sensor():
    microphone_sensor = wrapped_packet.microphone_sensor()
    print("sample_rate_hz", microphone_sensor.sample_rate_hz())
```

Hope this helps anyone else who's confused.